# I am doing cross domain tracking with ga4 for a hotel company but cant get the cookies through

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

The company's website has the first domain for the browsing and room selecting, when they click book now it takes them to the booking engine ( the second domain) and to bring the cookies over from one site to another should be enabled as we have setted up the cross domain perfectly. The problem here is that the cookies ARENT being transfered over since the second domain is blocking us out and we dont have access to the second domain. The client has only given us access to the first domain and cannot give us access to the second domain since it was made by a third party engine.

We have tried setting up cross domain using javescript manually and using the orginal ga wont work since it will be gone in july, we have have tried using an api (cross origin) and the cookies/ information counting it as a single user still will not transfer over. Keep in mind that the end goal is e-commerce tracking. We are currently trying to ethically hack into the website to give us access to the second domain to allow us through and enable us to properly set up the cross domain tracking, meanwhile do you guys have any help for this special case?